# printf() first character not displayed after using _getche()

Tags: c, windows

If I input `test` and press `[esc]`, the output is `he result is "test"` for some reason. The `T` gets removed from the beginning. But if I reach the limit of 20 characters, `The result is "..."` is displayed normally. The really weird part is, that when using certain characters before of the uppercase `T`, it is displayed, but when using others it remains the same (`he result is "..."`).
The code is as follows:

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include "conio.h"

int main()
{
    printf("conio.h _getche test\n\n");
    char text[21], c;
    int n = 0;
    printf("Please enter your text: ");
    while (1)
    {
        if (n == 20)
        {
            text[n] = 0;
            break;
        }
        c = _getche();
        if (c == 27)
        {
            text[n] = 0;
            break;
        }
        text[n] = c;
        n = n + 1;
    }
    printf("\n\nThe result is \"%s\"\n", text);
    return 0;
}
```

I'm really struggling to comprehend what is going on... All help is welcome, thanks in advance.

Comment: Bear in mind that _getche is not a standard C function.

Comment: I don't get that result in the Windows command prompt.  What OS/IDE are you using?  My guess is printing the ESC character triggers some kind of escape sequence in the IDE that eats a few characters.

Comment: @EugeneSh the ESC is printed before the last `printf` by `_getche` (get character with echo).

Comment: @MarkTolonen Yeah, I realized that it is actually eating the characters from the output. This hypothesis is easy to test.

Comment: The easy test is `printf("%c\n\nThe\n", 27);` which should print `he` if the hypothesis is correct.

Comment: @user3386109 This `_getche` could also contribute though in some weird way

Comment: @EugeneSh. It's possible, but that's what the test will prove or disprove.

Comment: printf("%c\n\nThe\n", 27); does indeed return he
I'm using windows 10 and visual studio community 2022

Comment: My guess is that the console sees the ESC character and eats characters until it reaches the `T` and decides that's an invalid escape sequence. Or maybe it was a valid escape, but there's no immediately visible indication of what that sequence does.

Comment: @KarlKadak My suggestion would be to not use the in-built IDE console. I believe you can configure it to run in a native console instead.

Comment: *"If I input `test`"*. If you should also press <Enter> before pressing <Esc> the output will look strange, because there was no line feed, only a "carriage return". Apart from that, cannot replicate.

Comment: All right, thanks guys, I was just testing anyways and I've given up. From my side, everything was correct as far as I'm concerned :D. Still thanks for taking a look at it.

Comment: Aside: instead of `#include "stdio.h"` you should have `#include <stdio.h>` ditto for `conio.h`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I *think* what is happening is you are simply breaking the terminal’s sequence recognition software.

Almost all modern terminal emulators support [Virtual Terminal Control Sequences](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/console-virtual-terminal-sequences). Importantly, the **Windows Console** has also been updated to support VT sequences just as well as the **Windows Terminal**.

*Most* VT control sequences begin with an `Esc` character (`'\033'` or `(char)27`).

By using `_getche()`, you are sending that `Esc` sequence initializer to the terminal. And since escape sequences are a mess (not all of them begin with `ESC [`), the terminal patiently reads characters...

...until it gets that `'T'` and can definitively say “this is not a valid control sequence” — at which point it can do nothing but throw it all out and continue on as if nothing had happened. You loose random stuff and wonder what happened.

What you should learn from this is:

#### Don’t echo control characters back to the user

Obnoxiously, this means that you cannot really put `_getche()` to any good use. Remove it from your repertoire. If you *must* have an echoing function, write one that sanitizes its inputs:

```
int my_getche()
{
  int c = _getch();
  if ((c < 0x80) && isprint( c ))
  {
    putchar( c );
  }
  return c;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Dúthomhas . My problem has been solved :D